# Is it possible to allow login only (no registration) with external providers in Identity 2?

Tags: asp.net-identity-2

I have a closed-registration site (set up as a resellers control panel).

There is no way to sign up externally as the admin creates the accounts and dishes them out to users.

I wanted to allow the user to attach their social accounts (fb/twitter/etc) to their logins after they have been created to make it easier for them to sign in to the website in the future.

The problem I'm seeing is that there doesn't appear to be a way to modify the third party providers to only allow login if the account already exists?

I've looked around the documentation and can't find anything eg,:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.twitter.twitterauthenticationoptions_properties(v=vs.113).aspx

So the question is - can you setup asp.net identity 2.0 so that external login providers can be used to login but are rejected if they aren't already registered to an account on the site?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the default MVC 5 template. I have a list of authorized users in a separate table from the Identity users table. When a user attempts to log in via Google, I check the user against that table in the AccountController's ExternalLoginCallback method prior to the SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync() call. If they exist in the authorized users table, it continues the login process. If not, it redirects them back to the Login page. This of course requires knowing what their social login username or email address is in order to compare it, which in our case is not a problem because we are limiting login to specific users within our Google Apps domain.